# How do you store the value of a checked radio button in local storage using pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, local-storage, reload

I'd like to store my checked radio button in local storage so that on a page reload it will have the last checked item check on the reload.

Html:

```
<h3>Seconds Display:</h3>
<p id="secondsHidingText">Hiding seconds extends battery life</p>
&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="seconds" value="show" checked="checked">Show&nbsp&nbsp
<input type="radio" name="seconds" value="hide">Hide
```

This is the javascript I have:

```
localStorage.setItem('seconds', options.seconds);
```

(which runs when the save button I have is clicked)

And

```
document.getElementById('seconds').value = localStorage.getItem("seconds");
```

(which runs on document being loaded)

I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`

How do I store and retrieve the checked radio button to and from local storage?  And if possible I'm looking for a pure JS way of accomplishing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling the JS on the page? Sounds like its unable to find the input by the id. Do you have a fiddle or link to the live page?

Comment: Not sure how I overlooked it, but there is no element shown with an id of `seconds`.

Comment: Here's a link to the page:  https://barrydoyle18.github.io/remindMeConfig.html
Please excuse the hey alert...

Comment: Yeah that's it!!  I can't believe I missed that either!  Thanks for spotting it :)

Comment: No problem. I've been there plenty of times myself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would have to iterate through the radio buttons and then set the value. Something like this

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("seconds"); // list of radio buttons
var val = localStorage.getItem('seconds'); // local storage value
for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++){
  if(radios[i].value == val){
      radios[i].checked = true; // marking the required radio as checked
  }
}
```

I used jquery only to set the localstorage value in a convenient way.

Here is a ***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4jaemaL6/2/)***

Comment: please let me know if it doesn't work. Sometimes jsfiddle is creating a problem.

Comment: perfect example! can you please make one more for cookies? How should I get element from there?