# How can you show a radio button selection on a refreshed page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to coding and I apologise if my English is bad. I have a group of radio buttons and when I clicked it, It shows my tables but filtered for the selection. So if maths is selected from the 3, only the records with maths will be shown then I can export or print this data. but the problem is that when I selection maths it unchecks the radio so the export button cant be pressed because there is no button selected.

Is there any way to keep the button selected?

I try to use `localStorage.setItem("radio", value);` but this did not work too

my html and script:

```
<div>
<input type="radio" name="download" id="1" value="/mathsrecord"/>Math <br />
<input type="radio" name="download" id="2" value="/englishrecord"/>English <br />
<input type="radio" name="download" id="2" value="/accountingrecord"/>Acc <br />
<input type="radio" name="download" id="3" value="/all"/>All <br />
        </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="download" value="download">Export to Excel</button>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                $('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() {
                     window.location = $(this).val();
                     localStorage.setItem("radio", value);
                });
                </script>
<script>
var radio_1 = document.getElementById('1');
var radio_2 = document.getElementById('2');
var radio_3 = document.getElementById('3');
var button = document.getElementById('download');

button.onclick = downloadFile;

function downloadFile() {
    if(radio_1.checked) {
        window.open("/exportmath/excel");
    }else if(radio_2.checked) {
        window.open("/exporteng/excel");
    } else if(radio_3.checked) {
      window.open("/exportacc/excel");
    }
}</script>
```

Comment: _“I try to use localStorage.setItem("radio", value); but this did not work too”_ - what did you _expect_ it to do? Storing the value on its own, is not going to affect how your radio buttons will behave. You still need to implement the second part of this - _reading_ this value from localstorage, when the page loads, and then _setting_ the according radio button to checked.

Comment: could you link me a article?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29755453/1427878 has an example; if you need more than that, then please do a bit of research yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value back to radio button after reloading a page.

Like this

```
var itemValue = localStorage.getItem("radio");
if (itemValue !== null) {
   $("input[value=\""+itemValue+"\"]").click();
}
```